# Set query filter of mongoose based on request params in typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So ultimately I need to do mongoose find in my use case but before that i need to create a dynamic query to filter data while fetching.
I have created a testInterface which has two field first is the action and the second is the value, action has the name of fields present in my mongoose model.

```
interface testInterface {
  action:
    | "testValue1"
    | "testValue2"
    | "testValue3"
    | "testValue4"
    | "testValue5";
  value: number;
}
```

I am receiving the mongoose model field value from the req params, i need to use this value as action value and do my search.

```
      var testquery: testInterface = { action: req.params.choice, value: 1 };
```

but follwoing error is thrown -

Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"testValue1" | "testValue2" | "testValue3" | "testValue4" | "testValue5"'.ts(2322)
userChoice.tsx(29, 3): The expected type comes from property 'action' which is declared here on type 'testInterface'

Please suggest how can i achieve the following use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to manually convert your string value to the corresponding union type value:

```
interface testInterface {
  action:
    | "testValue1"
    | "testValue2"
    | "testValue3"
    | "testValue4"
    | "testValue5";
  value: number;
}

var testquery: testInterface = { action: convert(req.params.choice), value: 1 };

function convert(strVal: string) : testInterface["action"] {
  switch (strVal) {
     case "testValue1":
       return "testValue1";
     case "testValue2":
       return "testValue2";
     case "testValue3":
       return "testValue3";
     case "testValue4":
       return "testValue4";
     case "testValue5":
       return "testValue5";
     default:
       throw new Error("Unsupported type");
  }
}
```